# Deserialize json array to vb .NET object exception - Cannot serialize into because type requires array

Tags: json, vb.net

I am following the guidelines for deserializing my array but can't figure out why I keep getting this exception. I have also tried this with a non-empty json string unlike the one below.

```
Private Class lobbActivity
    Public Property billNum_List() As String
    Public Property ruleOrReg_List() As String
    Public Property ratemaking_List() As String
    Public Property PcontrNum_List() As String
    Public Property Ptitle_List() As String
    Public Property MuniOrd_List() As String
    Public Property MuniRed_List() As String
    Public Property ExOrders_List() As String
    Public Property TribeSub_List() As String
    Public Property Tribes_List() As String
End Class

Function JSONCreateLobbyist(ByVal activityArr As String)
     Dim item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of lobbActivity())(activityArr)
```

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txhZv.png)

```
{"billNum_List":["aa","aa"],"ruleOrReg_List":["vbb","vbb"],"ratemaking_List":["bb","bb"],"PcontrNum_List":[],"Ptitle_List":[],"MuniOrd_List":[],"MuniRed_List":[],"ExOrders_List":[],"TribeSub_List":[],"Tribes_List":[]}
```

Ended up using different syntax that worked

```
Dim act As lobbActivity = js.Deserialize(Of lobbActivity)(activityArr)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Paste as JSON feature in Visual Studio, it does not define array properties correctly.

```
Private Class lobbActivity
    Public Property billNum_List As String()
    Public Property ruleOrReg_List As String()
    Public Property ratemaking_List As String()
    Public Property PcontrNum_List As String()
    Public Property Ptitle_List As String()
    Public Property MuniOrd_List As String()
    Public Property MuniRed_List As String()
    Public Property ExOrders_List As String()
    Public Property TribeSub_List As String()
    Public Property Tribes_List As String()
End Class
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception, I think I need to add JsonObjectAttribute to the type

Comment: Ended up trying a different way and it worked.                                                Dim act As lobbActivity = js.Deserialize(Of lobbActivity)(activityArr)

Answer (score 2):

Your properties are not arrays they are strings. Use the following modified class

```
Private Class lobbActivity
    Public Property billNum_List() As String()
    Public Property ruleOrReg_List() As String()
    Public Property ratemaking_List() As String()
    Public Property PcontrNum_List() As String()
    Public Property Ptitle_List() As String()
    Public Property MuniOrd_List() As String()
    Public Property MuniRed_List() As String()
    Public Property ExOrders_List() As String()
    Public Property TribeSub_List() As String()
    Public Property Tribes_List() As String()
End Class
```