# Deserializing JSON in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to deserialize this string, it is from a rest api, but i dont know how to do it.

i know i have to create a class with the struture of the string, and i have to run the command with deserialize.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

```
"
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "categories": {
      "17": [
        {
          "category_id": "17",
          "name": "Software",
          "description": "",
          "sort_order": "4",
          "meta_title": "",
          "meta_description": "",
          "meta_keyword": "",
          "language_id": "1",
          "image": "http://newapi3.opencart-api.com/image/cache/catalog/categories/12316636179756542373092288841575795860377n-100x100.jpg",
          "categories": null
        },
        {
          "category_id": "17",
          "name": "Software",
          "description": "",
          "sort_order": "4",
          "meta_title": "",
          "meta_description": "",
          "meta_keyword": "",
          "language_id": "2",
          "image": "http://newapi3.opencart-api.com/image/cache/catalog/categories/12316636179756542373092288841575795860377n-100x100.jpg",
          "categories": null
        }
      ],
      "18": [
        {
          "category_id": "18",
          "name": "Laptops &amp; Notebooks",
          "description": "&lt;p&gt;\r\n\tShop Laptop feature only the best laptop deals on the market. By comparing laptop deals from the likes of PC World, Comet, Dixons, The Link and Carphone Warehouse, Shop Laptop has the most comprehensive selection of laptops on the internet. At Shop Laptop, we pride ourselves on offering customers the very best laptop deals. From refurbished laptops to netbooks, Shop Laptop ensures that every laptop - in every colour, style, size and technical spec - is featured on the site at the lowest possible price.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
          "sort_order": "2",
          "meta_title": "",
          "meta_description": "",
          "meta_keyword": "",
          "language_id": "1",
          "image": "http://newapi3.opencart-api.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/hp_2-100x100.jpg",
          "categories": null
        },
        {
          "category_id": "18",
          "name": "Laptops &amp; Notebooks",
          "description": "&lt;p&gt;\r\n\tShop Laptop feature only the best laptop deals on the market. By comparing laptop deals from the likes of PC World, Comet, Dixons, The Link and Carphone Warehouse, Shop Laptop has the most comprehensive selection of laptops on the internet. At Shop Laptop, we pride ourselves on offering customers the very best laptop deals. From refurbished laptops to netbooks, Shop Laptop ensures that every laptop - in every colour, style, size and technical spec - is featured on the site at the lowest possible price.&lt;/p&gt;\r\n",
          "sort_order": "2",
          "meta_title": "",
          "meta_description": "",
          "meta_keyword": "",
          "language_id": "2",
          "image": "http://newapi3.opencart-api.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/hp_2-100x100.jpg",
          "categories": null
        }
      ]
     }
  }
}"
```

Comment: `"i know i have to create a class with the struture of the string, and i have to run the command with deserialize."` - Did you try that?  What class did you create?  What de-serialization did you use?  For example, Newtonsoft's JSON.NET has a simple serializer/de-serializer for this.

Comment: copy the JSON string to clip board, then in visual studio, create a new class, and use the Edit | PAste Special | Paste as JSON command, and it will generate classes for you if the JSON is well formed. Be aware that there is a bug in how it declares array properties as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139704/deserialize-json-array-to-vb-net-object-exception-cannot-serialize-into-becau/35140474#35140474

Comment: @rlima please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this service](http://jsonutils.com/) to generate classes from JSON strings. It will save you a lot of time (and headache).

After that, you might consider using a third-party library for deserializing the JSON string. You have quite a few options but the most popular and the best according to me, is [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

After you have installed it, you can go forward and access whatever data you want after deserializing the JSON.

#### Example:

```
Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of YourDataClass)("<YourJSONString>");
If data.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(data.Data.Categories(0).Name);
End If
```

Comment: Question is tagged as `vb.net`, so "this service" didn't save a time and headache :)

Comment: @Fabio Added an alternative which works just as fine.